# blur() CSS afecta el texto y no el background

Tags: css, filtro, blur

Por que el filtro de CSS afecta al texto y no a la imagen, el background esta dentro del body, o es el mismo body, como consigo aplicar este filtro solo a el background?
Alguna manera de manejar el backgroun aparte, ya intente ponerlo como etiqueta en el body e igual se modifica todo el texto y no la imagen.

```css
.titulo{
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="window"lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stylish&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
    body {
      background: url("http://i.imgur.com/yqPxEl7.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      filter: blur(0.1rem);
    }
    </style>
    <div class="titulo">
      <h1>Sample text</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que el fallo es que estás asignando `blur()` a el elemento `<body>`, pero al `background` no.

Comment: Y como podria solucionar eso?

Answer (score -2):

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #fff;
}

.page-bg {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/yqPxEl7.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.1rem);
  -moz-filter: blur(0.1rem);
  -o-filter: blur(0.1rem);
  -ms-filter: blur(0.1rem);
  filter: blur(0.1rem);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.titulo{
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="window" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stylish&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-bg"> <!-- No colocar contenido --></div>
    <h1 class="titulo">This is a title</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son únicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor revisa [Cómo escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).